# Huge slowdown when packing arguments into derived type with pointers in Fortran

Tags: performance, pointers, fortran, argument-passing

I have a complicated structure which a driver subroutine calls several user libraries. Many arguments need to be passed. To avoid the possibility of making a mistake, I decided to pack the arguments in a derived type structure and use pointers. I've noticed that this packing makes a big slow-down. I've made a working example with the two alternatives. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/258337/stackoverflow/working_example.f90 uses the derived type while the https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/258337/stackoverflow/working_example_alt.f90 passes the arguments directly. The real system is much more complicated than this but this is representative of what happens.

I compile both with -O2 and use time to measure their performance:

```
$ ifort -O2 -o test working_example_alt.f90 && time ./test 
real    0m0.769s
user    0m0.768s
sys 0m0.000s
$ ifort -O2 -o test working_example.f90 && time ./test 
real    0m1.441s
user    0m1.444s
sys 0m0.000s
```

The same slowdown happens with gfortran as well. I use Linux Debian 7.0.

Here are some profiling examples (using Intel Vtune) that show the delay inside one library for the original system. Small case:
[image: Small case]
Bigger case, same library:
[image: Bigger case]

I expected some overhead but not that significant... Is this normal? Is it due to the pointer association at each driver call? Or some optimizations are disabled? Or simply the passing of a derived type instead of intrinsic? Should the associate construct cost that much?

This was cross-posted on https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/510037

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Optimizers often appear to be smarter than programmers writing tests for optimizers ;)

Comment: @IanH Modified the examples to include loop dependencies and avoid the optimization of the compiler. Thanks for catching that one!!!

Comment: Did you use a profiler to find the hot-spot?

Comment: @VladimirF I have included in the post the profiling of the program using Vtune. As you can see, there is a cost flagging the associate construct and extra time spent for the same simple computations.

Comment: Seems like the compiler is generating pointers.

Comment: (1) With your latest samples (to avoid certain loop optimizations) I get the same timings with ifort 14.0.2 and `-Ofast` regardless of the implementation. (2) I wanted to point out that the way you use the derived type is very weird: you first have separate variables which later get grouped in the derived type, and the you pass the derived type along together with the separate variables like `x(1)`. This doesn't make sense to me. If data is to be grouped, it makes more sense to use a derived type from the start and have library routines deal with the derived type directly, without `associate`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're looking for in terms of an answer... My experience with fortran oop and pointers is that, yes, that cause some fairly significant overhead.

I used OOP to write a fluid dynamics code for students - and it is safe and readable which is why I used OOP. But when I profiled the code I found that taking out the pointer references in some key parts of the code (the iterative pressure solver) gave me a speed up of a factor of two (~4 minutes run time down to 2).

So, pointers adding .2s doesn't seem impossible, but I can't say if that is your only issue from the information given. I guess a tip might be to develop with OOP (which was very fast and safe), and then optimize the pieces that actually matter for performance.